# Kubernetes change kubelet config at all cluster

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubelet

I need add argument `--authentication-token-webhook` in Kubelet. I can change file `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` at all nodes step by step with my hands. But it is not funny )). How can I change Kubelet arguments from single point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either

1. configure your Kubernetes workers via tools like [Puppet](https://puppet.com/) or [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/). Write your service drop-in once and deploy it via the tool to all nodes. Make sure you don't restart all kubelets at once (keyword serial for Ansible). Also, don't change `10-kubeadm.conf`, drop in another file like `20-kubeadm-extra-args.conf` and set the environment variable `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS`.
2. or use a Kubernetes feature called [DynamicKubeletConfig](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/). Beware that this is an alpha feature (as of Kubernetes 1.10) and has to be enabled by hand. I wouldn't recommend this method (yet, as long as it's an alpha feature), but it might become a feasible option in the future.

Comment: info: `DynamicKubeletConfig` is now Beta